# Top users with posts mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, mysqli

I have 2 tables users | posts.

The `posts` structure is:

[`post_id` | `post_user_id` ]

The `users` structure is:

[`user_id` | `user_name`| `user_password` ]

Now i want to get the top 5 user with posts

edit 1:

```
       $cod_sql = "select u.user_name, count(*) as 'TotalNumberofPosts'
from users u
  join posts p
    on u.user_id=p.post_user_id
group by user_name
order by count(*) desc 
limit 5";
        $top10 = mysql_query($cod_sql1) or die (error_sql(mysql_error(),__LINE__,__FILE__));

            echo '<div class="head_panel">Members</div> 
                    <div class="body_panel">
                <table border="1" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr class="tr3">
                Top5 : 
                    </tr>';

    if ( $top10 === FALSE ) 
    { 
        // An error has occured 
        print "There was an error running the query" . mysql_error(); 
    } else { 
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($top10) ) 
        { 
            print "This is some data from a row<BR />"; 
            print "Name: ($row) <BR />"; 
        } 
    }  

          }
        break;
```

Comment: Top 5 users with top posts

Comment: Do you mean top 5 users with the most posts?

Comment: yes , but i want the result to show their usernames

Comment: while the only common between posts and users is the user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will calculate the total number of posts for each user and display only the top 5 posters.  [SQL Fiddle demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ca02/3/0).

```
select u.user_name, count(*) as 'TotalNumberofPosts'
from users u
  join posts p
    on u.user_id=p.post_user_id
group by user_name
order by count(*) desc 
limit 5
```

Comment: The SQL statement I provided will return the top 5. This is denoted by the last line of the query "Limit 5". The only thing that needs to be done now is write the supporting PHP code to display the information. The link I provided above gives an example of how to fetch the information and display it.

Comment: i did , but result was nothing , page was empty

Comment: Did you modify the code found on the link to work with your table structure?

Comment: Does the data in post have corresponding data in the user table? If not, joining the tables together would not work.

Comment: Have other queries displayed using this data?  Like select * from users

Comment: yes , i have page shows all members , shows them normal

Comment: To eliminate the possibility this is a SQL issue, I suggest using a tool to query your database directly and supplying it with the query provided.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will do. I cant verify right now the script, so tell me if it works.

```
select * 
from users
where exists (
     select * from posts
     where users.user_id=posts.post_user_id)
order by users.user_id
limit 5
```

Comment: maybe because i used mysql_query ?

Comment: i guess you are not fetching the results.